# Nodejs stream, how to indicate to piped streams the original one has no more data

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I am trying node streams because everyone says it's easy even though the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) is hundreds of pages without even mentioning what things actually do the online examples are very simple.

I have the following code:

```
const { PassThrough } = require("node:stream");
let time = 4000;
const one = new PassThrough({
  objectMode: true,
  transform(chunk, enc, callback) {
    console.log("in one:", chunk);
    callback(null, chunk);
  },
});
const two = new PassThrough({
  objectMode: true,
  transform(chunk, enc, callback) {
    //added some async for good measure
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("in two:", chunk);
      callback(null, chunk);
    }, (time -= 1000));
  },
});
const task = one.pipe(two);
one.on("end", (...args) => {
  console.log("end of one:", args);
});
two.on("end", (...args) => {
  console.log("end of two:", args);
});
task.on("end", (...args) => {
  console.log("end of task:", args);
});
//reading task will trigger on end for one and task
// task.on("data", () => {
//   88;
// });
const recur = (times) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (times > 3) {
      //none of these things will cause task or two to
      //  trigger end
      console.log("pushing null");
      one.push(null);
      one.end();
      return;
    }
    one.write(times);
    recur(times + 1);
  }, 100);
};
recur(1);
```

My question is what can I do to stream `one` that causes `two` and `task` to trigger `end`? Is there a method I can invoke on a stream that indicates there is no more data and streams reading from it (through pipe) will close when last data is read?

Comment: `readable.push(null)` will signify the end of the data for that stream.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for the tip, I tried it in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stream-vls350?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A34%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A31%7D%5D) but unless I add a listener to the data event of task the end event will not trigger. I have also updated the code in the question to the code used in the sandbox.

Comment: I don't honestly follow what your code is trying to do.  But, if a stream is not flowing (nobody is reading its data), it won't ever get to the end.  Attaching a `data` event listener is one way to make the stream flow.